# count rows in one table based on the id's of the other table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
Orders
Orders product
```

I currently have the query that counts the amounts of orders:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM orders WHERE DATE(`created_on`) = CURDATE()
```

This gives me the amount of orders from today

Now I want to change this query, so insted of that I count the orders I count the amount of products that they ordered.

The order_products table is like this:

```
-id
-order_id
-product_name
-product_weight 
etc etc
```

I am only interested in the order_id because that links this table to the orders table.  For every product that is ordered, 1 row is added in this table linked to the order with the order_id.

Is it possible to have one single query to select the count of that, or is that not possible? I think I have to use a LEFT JOIN for this operation, but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create inner join between those table and applying the relation throw foreign key then you need to add group by condition on what you are looking for

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM orders o inner join order_product op on(op.order_id=o.order_id) WHERE DATE(`created_on`) = CURDATE() group by op.id
```

Comment: Thank you! THis is the answer!

Comment: Accept the answer in order to help The other people who are facing same problem

Comment: I know, I just had to wait 5 minutes before I could :) Just did, thanks again!